# Having problem in creating hover effect in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

well i have little knowledge in JavaScript.

My idea is to design a grid look so that whenever user drag some horizontal or vertical object on grid either horizontal or vertical line of gird hovers and he can have idea this is where i have to drop my object.

I have made gird using table specifying border-left,now i have grid of some column and row and for showing horizontal and vertical line i am using border with position absolute.now i am not getting how do i get position when mouse goes on border-left or border-right of table(td) so that i can place my border with that gives a hover effect

Comment: do you want something like this http://ushatech.com/customer/Palletized_Material_Handling_Conveyors/build.php?num1=50&num2=50

Comment: yes something like this but when i am dragging something want to create a horizontal or vertical line (depends on what is type of dragging element) that gives me hover like effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you searching to give effect to active `droppable` element, then this can help you 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-activeClass

Comment: yes it is drop-able but that is not my problem. my problem is show horizontal or vertical line that line must align with my grid that grid is again made up using table i have made table by specifying left,right,top,bottom border.now i have a border having absolute position that need to show whenever user drag component on grid

Comment: so, you can use `activeClass` to set css properties. which will be applied to the draggable element while an acceptable draggable is being dragged over it.